# Generating a heat map from IP Addresses

Tags: ip-address, heatmap, geography

I'm attempting to generate a geographical heat map out of a table of IP addresses to illustrate traffic to my website by geographic area. I have a ~300km*300km area I'd like to work in. I can probably figure out how to turn the IP addresses into latitude and longitute or geographic data of some sort, but how can I create a heat map from this? Is there a library that can do this?

Note: I'm working in mostly PHP/JS for this project, but I'd be willing to use a different technology to get this illustration made. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have lat/long (or other XY coordinate system) points, there are quite a few options for rendering. A couple that I am most familiar with:

- [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) is an open-source JavaScript library for mapping, and there's [a plugin for rendering heatmaps](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat).
- Use the ArcGIS JavaScript API's [HeatmapRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/renderer_heatmap_weighted.html). This gets slightly more complicated if you don't have access to either ArcGIS Online or an ArcGIS Server install; it's really simple to consume a feature layer with their API, possible but a bit complicated if you just have points.
- You can also use the [Google's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) or [Bing's](https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2012/11/13/create-heat-maps-with-bing-maps-and-dynamics-crm/) API.

All of these use JavaScript, so as long as you're cool with that, there are definitely plenty of options.